# Changing aspnetdb.mdf from ASP to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am using default ASP.NET membership provider and `aspnetdb.mdf` in `App_Data` folder. I then decided to delete `aspnetdb.mdf` from the `App_Data` folder and create a new one in SQL Server via `aspnet_regsql.exe` and modified the connection string accordingly.

Now while checking the role of the user I get an exception error which indicates that it still looks for `aspnetdb.mdf` at the old path (and not in SQL Server).

This is my code:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        // Code that runs on application startup
        if (!Roles.RoleExists("Administrator"))
        {
            Roles.CreateRole("Administrator");
        }

        if (Membership.GetUser("Admin") == null)
        {
            Membership.CreateUser("Admin", "mrtcn.1907");
            Roles.AddUserToRole("Admin", "Administrator");
        }
}
```

This is the exception I get:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\muratcan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MedicalBootStrap\MedicalBootStrap\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Here is the connection string;

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" 
     connectionString="data source=MRTCN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;User Id=medicalusr;Password=123456;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

There is most probably another place to be modified accordingly that it looks for the `aspnetdb.mdf` at the right path.

After Win's suggestion, I have changed the connection string accordingly

This is the modified connection string;

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" 
     connectionString="data source=MRTCN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;User  Id=medicalusr;Password=123456;AttachDBFilename=aspnetdb.mdf" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And this is the new exception;

> {"An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file aspnetdb.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."}

Comment: Have you updated the [ConnectionString](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) to point to new database? About connection string is still pointing to old LocalDB.

Comment: @Win I have added my connection string too, if "AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf" "DataDirectory" points to the MS SQL Path (not App_Data folder) then it probably points to new database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf` means your LocalDB.

If you connect to **SQL Server** instead of LocalDB, **ConnectionString** should be something like this -

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ApplicationServices" 
     connectionString="Data Source=MRTCN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DATABASE_NAME;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=medicalusr;Password=123456" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Sample [SqlConnection](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/standard-security/) string.

Comment: I have changed the connection string as you suggested now I get another exception, it still try to create an aspnetdb.mdf automatically. You can see the new exception in my question

Comment: @mctuna Do not use **AttachDBFilename** which is causing the problem. Instead, you want to use **[Initial Catalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.initialcatalog.aspx)**.

Comment: It still can not login to database with the username medicalusr but this is due to permissions probably, I gave it full control though, strange